# How can I pass arbitrary parameters to my mocha tests with mochaPhantomJS & gulp?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, gulp, mocha.js, mocha-phantomjs

I'm using gulp & mochaPhantomJS.  I'd like to use the same test html and run different tests against it.  How can I pass *arbitrary* parameters (by which I mean *not* the phantom args) that I can retrieve from within my test JavaScript?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var mochaPhantomJS = require('gulp-mocha-phantomjs');

gulp.task('testMisc', function() {
    return gulp.src('testMisc.html')
        .pipe(mochaPhantomJS());
});
```

But to be clear what I want to be able to do is

```
gulp.task('testMisc-1', function() {
    return gulp.src('testMisc.html')
        .pipe(mochaPhantomJS({whatever:1}));
});

gulp.task('testMisc-2', function() {
    return gulp.src('testMisc.html')
        .pipe(mochaPhantomJS({whatever:2}));
});
```